# CGImage to grayscale

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-graphics

Is there any easier and shorter way to convert `CGImage` to gray scale than

1. turning it to `CIImage`
2. apply `CIFilter`
3. turn to `NSBitmapImageRep` and then back to `CGImage`?

Comment: shorter in terms of? execution time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298867/convert-image-to-grayscale

Comment: @jimpic Execution time and memory consumption

Comment: @propstm its about UIImage turning to grayscale, and I am asking for CGImage to grayscale, and by the way, mine question is about doing it in os x.

Comment: you can always get a CGImage from a UIImage using [myImage CGImage]

Comment: It is not iOS. It is OS X, so I have no ability to use UIImage.