# Why Tesseract OCR library (iOS) cannot recognize text at all?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to use `Tesseract OCR` library in my iOS application. I downloaded tesseract-ios library from github and when I tried to recognize a simple text image I got garbage instead. Here is an image of what I tried to recognize:

[image]

I got unreadable text:

> T0I1101T0W  KIR1 H1I1101T0W  KIR1 H1I1101T0W  CIBEPS H1  ES PBHY P306
>   EHH11  133I R1 11335 11I1H1  19 13S  SYIL 3B19 M H300H1911 H1113 AIR1 
>   J1 OIII 3I9SH5H133IS  13V9 I1 Q1H211 E015  19 W331 H1  111SW

Why Tesseract can't recognise even simple image? Here is code which I used to instantiate Tesseract:

```
Tesseract* tesseractObject = [[Tesseract alloc] initWithDataPath:@"tessdata" language:@"eng"];
[tesseractObject setVariableValue:@"0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" forKey:@"tessedit_char_whitelist"];
[tesseractObject setImage:image];
[tesseractObject recognize];
NSLog(@"RECOGNISED= %@" , [tesseractObject recognizedText]);
```

Here is my project structure:

[image]

I added English testdata folder by reference. So what am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: do you have all the eng tessdata files included as it looks like your language files are not working as it is scanning and getting letter shapes

Comment: Where do you get the image from, is it part of your app bundle, downloaded from a website by the app or is it from the camera?

Comment: @AdamRichardson I use images from camera and images from the app bundle.Result still the same

Comment: Have you tried it without [tesseractObject setVariableValue:@"0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" forKey:@"tessedit_char_whitelist"]; as that is something that I dont have in my code

Comment: @AdamRichardson Thanks man:)It really helped. I removed this and all text was recognized precisely. But it really strange...Restricting characters to a specific set must only improve recognizing accuracy.So now i don't understand things at all.

Comment: glad it worked it is really odd as restricting characters would seem the logical thing to do

Comment: you may find this thread useful as well as it is about improving the accuracy of OCR from images taken with the camera http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511102/ios-tesseract-ocr-image-preperation/15528047#15528047

Comment: Perhaps you should try again, but this time include lower case letters in the whitelist...

Comment: how to all language pack use in my application but more than one size for language package , how to manage this one issue , if any now know please let me know..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest tessdata file from Google code

http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list

This will provide you with a list of tessdata files that you need to download and include in your app if you haven't already. In your case you will need tesseract-ocr-3.02.eng.tar.gz as you are looking for the English language files

The following article will show you where you need to install it. I read through this tutorial when I built my first Tesseract project and found it really useful

http://lois.di-qual.net/blog/install-and-use-tesseract-on-ios-with-tesseract-ios/

Comment: I used this tutorial when configured Tesseract. So don't you have some ideas how to solve this? I really need a help.Thanks

Comment: You should use pod so pod will take care of any files that need to be updated.

Answer (score 21):

You are using the option tessedit_char_whitelist with the value "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" which limits the character recognition to this list only. However the image that you want to process contains lower case characters, if you want to use this option you will have to include lower cases char too.

```
[tesseractObject setVariableValue:@"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" forKey:@"tessedit_char_whitelist"];
```

Answer (score 12):

Like Adam said, if you want good results, you'll have to do some image processing and configure some settings (white-listing certain characters, etc).

For anyone else stumbling upon this question, I've put together a **sample project** here that does some white-listing and image processing:https://github.com/mstrchrstphr/OCR-iOS-Example

Comment: @user3823935 in build settings under architectures remove the default value and add armv7 and armv7s.
this lib was'nt build against arm64 which is probably why you get the errors

Comment: if linker error then use "TesseractOCR.framework" use

Answer (score 0):

[image]

and my output is

[image]

Solution :

```
 tesseract.language = @"eng+fra";

tesseract.pageSegmentationMode = G8PageSegmentationModeAuto;
tesseract.engineMode  = G8OCREngineModeTesseractCubeCombined;
tesseract.image = [image.image g8_blackAndWhite];

tesseract.maximumRecognitionTime = 60.0;
[tesseract recognize];

NSLog(@"%@", tesseract.recognizedText);

reco_area.text = [tesseract recognizedText];
```

for tessdata 
[click here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/93276/implementing-tesseract-ocr-ios)

Answer (score 0):

whatever @ Adam Richardson explained is correct along with that add this 1) **scaleimage method for increase size of the image(dimensions increase)**

func scaleImage(image: UIImage, maxDimension: CGFloat) -> UIImage {

```
    var scaledSize = CGSize(width: maxDimension, height: maxDimension)
    var scaleFactor: CGFloat

    if image.size.width > image.size.height {
        scaleFactor = image.size.height / image.size.width
        scaledSize.width = maxDimension
        scaledSize.height = scaledSize.width * scaleFactor
    } else {
        scaleFactor = image.size.width / image.size.height
        scaledSize.height = maxDimension
        scaledSize.width = scaledSize.height * scaleFactor
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(scaledSize)
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scaledSize.width, height: scaledSize.height))
    let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return scaledImage!
}
```

2) store this eng.traineddata language file in filemanager

```
 func storeLanguageFile() throws{
    var fileManager: FileManager = FileManager.default
    let nsDocumentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
    let nsUserDomainMask = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
    let docDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    let path: String = docDirectory.appendingPathComponent("/tessdata/eng.traineddata")
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: path){
        var data: NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile((Bundle.main.resourcePath?.appending("/tessdata/eng.traineddata"))!)! as! NSData
        var error: NSError
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: docDirectory.appendingPathComponent("/tessdata"), withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        data.write(toFile: path, atomically: true)
    }
}
```

3) after that you can use https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage for **increase clarity of the image**

you can use this

```
func preprocessedImage(for tesseract: G8Tesseract!, sourceImage: UIImage!) -> UIImage! {
    var stillImageFilter: GPUImageAdaptiveThresholdFilter = GPUImageAdaptiveThresholdFilter()
    stillImageFilter.blurRadiusInPixels = 4.0
    var filterImage: UIImage = stillImageFilter.image(byFilteringImage: sourceImage)
    return filterImage
}
```

these 3 steps will help you to  increase the accuracy of the tesseract upto 60 ~ 70 %

Comment: I got 70% accuracy text result from tesseract by using above 3 steps. But, I want to get text detection like address, firstName, lastName from this text