# Is there any "Tesseract OCR API" available for "IOS SDK 7.0"?

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5, tesseract

want to make an application in **IOS SDK 7.0** with **Xcode 5** that required **"Tesseract OCR API"**. So, Is there any **"Tesseract OCR API"** available for **"IOS SDK 7.0"** ? if any, please post the download link.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is an SDK that is iOS 7 compatible There are clear instruction on how to implement it in your application on there as well

[Tesseract OCR iOS](https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS)

You may also find these articles useful when working with Tesseract in iOS

[iOS Tesseract OCR Image Preparation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511102/ios-tesseract-ocr-image-preperation/15528047#15528047)

[Tesseract Text recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169148/why-tesseract-ocr-library-ios-cannot-recognize-text-at-all/17170092#17170092)