# Linker errors when using tesseract

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, tesseract

I have built an app that runs on Tesseract provided by Google. I followed a tutorial from [here](http://lois.di-qual.net/blog/install-and-use-tesseract-on-ios-with-tesseract-ios/). This is quite outdated but this was the only tutorial that i could find that uses objective c. So i improvised a bit and used the TesseractOCR framework instead of the tesseract-ios and tesseract-ios-lib files. After following through the tutorial i encountered this error[image: The error that i encountered]

To fix this issue i disabled Bitcode. After that i had 47 linker errors.[image: Image of the linker errors]

How do i fix this issue? Is there a updated version of the TesseractORC framework that i am supposed to download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used below link for my image processing task that may help you 
https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS 
And follow these steps. [Why Tesseract OCR library (iOS) cannot recognize text at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169148/why-tesseract-ocr-library-ios-cannot-recognize-text-at-all/41256753#41256753)

Comment: After following that tutorial, i am facing this error  `Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_G8Tesseract", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o`