# UIImage Pixel setting RGB Value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, rgb

All  what I want to do is to check a specific pixel's RGB value and so the same to the pixel next to it, and set the RGB value for the first pixel to the a range between two pixel's RGB values

here's the code

```
   int width = img.size.width;
int height = img.size.height;


// the pixels will be painted to this array
uint32_t *pixels = (uint32_t *) malloc(width * height * sizeof(uint32_t));

// clear the pixels so any transparency is preserved
memset(pixels, 0, width * height * sizeof(uint32_t));

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

// create a context with RGBA pixels
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, width, height, 8, width * sizeof(uint32_t), colorSpace,
                                             kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

// paint the bitmap to our context which will fill in the pixels array
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), [img CGImage]);

//allocate pixels array
for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        uint8_t *rgbaPixel1 = (uint8_t *) &pixels[y * width + x];
        uint8_t *rgbaPixel2 = (uint8_t *) &pixels[y * width + x + 1];
        //uint32_t color = r * rgbaPixel[RED] + g * rgbaPixel[GREEN] + b * rgbaPixel[BLUE];
        // set the pixels to the color
        rgbaPixel1[0] = (rgbaPixel1[0] + rgbaPixel2[0] / 2);
        rgbaPixel1[1] = (rgbaPixel1[1] + rgbaPixel2[1] / 2);
        rgbaPixel1[2] = (rgbaPixel1[2] + rgbaPixel2[2] / 2);
        rgbaPixel1[3] = 255;
    }
}
```

but all what I get is some funny results !

any help ? 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code to add 2 thin red lines at right and left of an image.
That worked with iOS7

```
-(UIImage*)ModifyImage:(UIImage*) img
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.size);

    [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,img.size.width,img.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeSourceOut alpha:1.0f];

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    int w =img.size.width;
    int cw,ch;

    cw = img.size.width / 35;
    ch = img.size.height / 35;

    unsigned char* data = CGBitmapContextGetData (ctx);

    for(int y = 0 ; y < img.size.height ; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0 ; x < img.size.width ; x++)
        {
            //int offset = 4*((w * y) + x);

            int offset = (CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(ctx)*y) + (4 * x);

            int blue    =  data[offset];
            int green   = data[offset+1];
            int red     = data[offset+2];
            //int alpha   = data[offset+3];

            if(x <= (cw * 2) || x >= (cw * 35))
            {
                data[offset]    = 0;
                data[offset+1]  = 0;
                data[offset+2]  = 255;
                data[offset+3]  = 255;
            }
        }
    }

    UIImage *rtimg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return rtimg;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

See these links,

**Getting pixel RGB**

[iPhone : How to change color of particular pixel of a UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462129/iphone-how-to-change-color-of-particular-pixel-of-a-uiimage)

[How to get pixel data from a UIImage (Cocoa Touch) or CGImage (Core Graphics)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics)

[Getting RGB pixel data from CGImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073259/getting-rgb-pixel-data-from-cgimage)

**Setting pixel RGB**

[iPhone : How to change color of particular pixel of a UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462129/iphone-how-to-change-color-of-particular-pixel-of-a-uiimage)

Comment: A list of links is not a good [SO] answer.  Please explain the detail of what is going on in the links, in order for it to become a useful answer.  Not only is it irritating to have to click through links to get the answer, but the links likely will become dead links at some point and no longer be a useful answer.